# Which virtual font is my document using?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I want to make some small changes to the kerning of a virtual font. The instructions for that (in various SE threads, etc) seem fairly straightforward, except for one thing: how can I find exactly which font I need to change?

For example, suppose I run this MWE with `pdflatex` in TexLive 2016:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[p,space=1.2]{erewhon}

\begin{document}
123
\end{document}
```

If I look in `C:/texlive/2016/textmf-dist/fonts/vs/public/erewhon`, I see 156 `.vf` files. The file names eliminate most of them as likely possibilities, but there are about 20  `Erewhon-Regular-*.vf` that might be the one I'm using.

If there is some infomation in the `.log` file, which answers the question, I'm getting lost trying to find it:

```
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
    File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
    )
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
...
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
    Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
    )
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty
    Package: mweights 2016/12/09 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight 
    font packages. 
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 21.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 29.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 37.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 56.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 75.
    )
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
    Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    \etb@tempcnta=\count87
    )
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
    Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
    LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
    )
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
    Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
    \XKV@toks=\toks14
    \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
    \XKV@depth=\count88
    File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
    ))
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+erewhon-LF on input lin
    e 142.

    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/erewhon/t1erewhon-lf.fd
    File: T1erewhon-LF.fd 2014/09/11 (autoinst) Font definitions for T1/erewhon-LF.

    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/erewhon-LF/m/n' will be
    (Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 142.
    )
    No file test.aux.
    \openout1 = `test.aux'.

    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LY1/ptm/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LY1+ptm on input line 4.
    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ly1/ly1ptm.fd
    File: ly1ptm.fd 2001/02/01 font definitions for LY1/ptm using Berry names.
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
    LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4.

    (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
    File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
    )
    LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
    \c@mv@tabular=\count89
    \c@mv@boldtabular=\count90
     [1

    {c:/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ) 
    Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
     1943 strings out of 493013
     26914 string characters out of 6136993
     71052 words of memory out of 5000000
     5514 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
     7932 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
     1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
     28i,4n,34p,800b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
    {
    c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/erewhon/zut1_n7tjt2.enc}<c:/texlive/
    2016/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/erewhon/Erewhon-Regular.pfb>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the example as `test.tex` and run

```
pdflatex -recorder test && grep '\.vf$' test.fls
```

You'll get

```
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/public/erewhon/Erewhon-Regular-lf-t1.vf
```

on the terminal.

This is for a Unix based system; I believe similar techniques exist on Windows. Anyway, the created `test.fls` file will contain the required information.

Comment: Yup, `pdflatex -recorder` works on Windows, which is the most important part of the answer.

Comment: @alephzero Sorry, but not having Windows on any of my machines, I'm quite impaired in knowing what tools are available. `;-)`

Comment: Well, I could have run your exact command using `GNU make` from `mingw` on Windows, but just editing `test.fls` was less typing!

Comment: Actually, this answer is a bit ironic, because I normally compile with `latexmk`, and that automatically uses the `-recorder` option to keep track of what files were used. But I didn't join the dots and realize that already answered my own question!